# Can classes reduce unconscious racial bias?

Tags: psychology, work, racism

Recently on PBS Newshour there was a [segment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sm-SLS3Hn2E) about Silicon Valley and their attempts to hire more diverse employees. A focus of the segment was employee training seminars about unconscious biases--where employees do exercises in order to make themselves more aware and careful about these biases.

Studies I've read have demonstrated that racial stereotyping is very real and very instantaneous--and exists among people of all races. But is there any scientific support for these classes being effective in reducing this unconscious bias?

Comment: It would be good to link to some of these classes to see what they claim. I would guess they don't claim to reduce unconscious racial bias, but give tools to help consciously overcome that bias, making the question title slightly inaccurate.

Comment: I'm guessing the line of thought here involves feedback - if you're taught to recognize when you're unconsciously applying stereotypes, you can stop yourself from *acting* on them quite so often.

Comment: @Shadur Agreed. You couldn't use instantaneous reactions to demonstrate the effectiveness of the classes.

Comment: You need to feed them anti racist propaganda. Do it for a month and the results will be nice if done correctly.

Comment: this is related https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/41176/is-the-implicit-association-test-effective-at-determining-an-individuals-biases